# Connection Pool Laravel Postgress

Tags: база-данных, laravel, postgresql, pool

У меня есть внешняя база данных, то бишь та которая работает на сервере.
Локально у меня работает Laravel приложение.

Проблема: первый даже самый простой SQL запрос (Eloquent) выполняется ~2 сек., все последующие запросы в рамках этого процесса выполняются с приемлемой скоростью (~100-200мс.).

Мне нужно локально избавиться от задержки в 2 секунды, как это можно сделать? Первое что приходит в голову это пул соединений в Laravel, чтобы каждый раз не создавалось новое. Может хранить их в редисе или что-то вроде того.
Видел кто-то пытался на Swoole писать что-то такое, но это далеко не прод решение.